# Appending char pointer after shallow copying

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have made two object of string class each having char* pointer . By shallow copying, i have copied the first object into second object by shallow copying . Now both of them pointing at the same location.

What i have to do is append the char pointer through one object so that it does not make another but increase the size of original char pointer so second object point to the same location.

```
void String::append(char c) {

    auto_ptr<StringBuffer> newdata(new StringBuffer);
    newdata.get()->reserve(this->_str->length() + 1);
    newdata.get()->smartCopy(this->_str);
    this->_str = newdata.release();
    this->_str->append(c);

 }
```

The wrapper class of StringBuffer

```
void StringBuffer::reserve(int n) {
if (_length < n) {
    int newlength = n; //max(_length*2,n);
    char* newbuf = new char[newlength];
    //copy contents of the stored string in the new buffer
    revSmartCopy(newbuf);

    //return stuff from the new buffer to the stored buffer
    delete[] this->_strbuf;
    this->_strbuf = newbuf;
    this->_length = newlength;
    newbuf = 0;

}
}
void StringBuffer::revSmartCopy(char* newString) {
int it = 0;
while (it < this->_length) {
    newString[it] = this->_strbuf[it];
    it++;
}
}

void StringBuffer::smartCopy(StringBuffer* newString) {
int shorterLength = 0;
(this->_length < newString->_length) ? shorterLength = this->_length : shorterLength = newString->_length;
int it = 0;
while (it < shorterLength) {
    *_strbuf++ = *(newString->_strbuf)++;
    it++;
}
}
```

This code is making another copying with object from whom we append pointing to new copy and older one pointing to previous

Comment: First, this is not `C`.  Second, `auto_ptr` -- this has been deprecated in favor of `std::unique_ptr`.  Third, what's the purpose of all of this code?  Is there something missing in `std::string` that you feel that you must implement yourself?

Comment: This is actually a task to implement owned pointer and perform string operation on it.

Comment: To append a character doesn't take all of these things you posted.  All it takes is a reallocation, copy, deallocate, assign.  All of this `StringBuffer` stuff, I have no idea what its purpose is.   Also, "*i have copied the first object into second object by shallow copying . Now both of them pointing at the same location.*" -- So if I take what you said here, when the destructor is called on these objects, you will get a double-delete error where you're deallocating the pointer address more than once.

Comment: I have taken care of that aspect by introducing the bool variable giving the right of deletion to lvalue object

Comment: *I have taken care of that aspect by introducing the bool variable* -- I will say with almost 100% conviction that this is not going to work or at the very least, is as fragile as fine glass and can be easily broken.  A simple `bool` variable can in no way cover all the ways an object can be copied.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Use `std::string`.

Comment: It sounds like the actual crucial bits of code are missing. And possibly also your description of the specific problem you are having, rather than merely stating what you want to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you're doing this as an exercise, because it makes no sense otherwise.

You can't reallocate a pointer to a different size and have it at the same pointer value; this might happen accidentally, but it's impossible to enforce. Since the two objects are independent, the only way to make this work is *double indirection* - the pointer in your object points to a second pointer, which is the pointer to the character buffer.

You're also going to have a problem with destruction, because you have multiple objects with the same pointer. The standard library has `std::shared_ptr` to solve this very problem. If a pointer is *shared* between different objects, use `shared_ptr` to hold it.

Since there will only be one pointer to the actual character buffer, you can use `std::unique_ptr` for that one. You could use `std::auto_ptr` instead, and it will work fine as long as you don't try to copy it, but `unique_ptr` is a far better choice.